# How to round a value of a String to 2 decimal places

Tags: java, android, math, casting, rounding

I have a String which is taken from a JSON file. I need to convert it to double or int and then round it to 2 decimal places and if its an int, round to 1 digit

for example: if it is 76424443 it should be rounded to 76.4
or if it is 7.122345936298 should be rounded to 7.12

This is what I have done so far.

```
int value = Integer.parseInt(value1);
value1 = String.valueOf(Math.round(value));
```

I also do not know if the value is double or int, should be something that works with both.

Comment: Did you mean `76.424443`? Double will handle "int" values.

Comment: Don't understand how 76424443 should be converted to 76.4. May you explain a little more about what you want ?

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ as it is 76 millions, cant I show it 76.4 m ?!

Comment: @Gaëtan because it is a big unnecessary number, they normally show it like 76.4 m that means 76 millions and something... . That was what I wanted but if it is not possible, then I only need something to convert string to double and only show 2 floating points and if it has not floating points then only shows first 2 digits. like instead of 76424443 shows 76.

Comment: @DannyJj Those are two separate rounding problems. You should edit your question to say 76.4M to avoid more confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code :

```
Double value = Double.parseDouble(value1);
String value1 = "0";
if(value != null){
    if(value == (double) Math.round(value)){
        if(value/1000000000 > 1.0){
            value1 = String.format("%.1f G", value/1000000000);
        }
        else if(value/1000000 > 1.0){
            value1 = String.format("%.1f M", value/1000000);
        }
        else if(value/1000 > 1.0){
            value1 = String.format("%.1f K", value/1000);
        }
        else{
            value1 = String.format("%.1f", value);
        }
    }
    else{
        value1 = String.format("%.2f", value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to add % sign if it has floating point? I tried this but did not work. `value1 = String.format("%.2f %", value);`

Comment: In String.format, % is a special character. You should escape it and do `value1 = String.format("%.2f %%", value);`

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a BigDecimal. It will let you round your values to the precision you like. Have a look at this answer: [Set specific precision of a BigDecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482889/setting-specific-precision-of-a-big-decimal)

If you cast a decimal value to integer then you will lose the decimal part. If that is the case then why bother rounding at all ?

Comment: Thanks for you answer, it seems does the job, but how should I change it to work in my case. I mean what does 12 mean that the user uses in that question?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation. It will provide detailed info. Plus,  search for tutorials.