# Java - How To Show Decimals with BigDecimal pow

Tags: java, math, bigdecimal

I'm currently stuck trying the following.

I have managed to store two values as BigDecimals, I have also managed to divide these values and show the chosen amount of decimals.

Current fields:

```
BigDecimal latestPopulation, earliestPopulation, gip, divider;
```

Like so:

```
latestPopulation = new BigDecimal(aInterger.toString());
earliestPopulation = new BigDecimal(bInterger.toString());
divider = latestPopulation.divide(earliestPopulation, 10, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

I then need to use the power of like so:

```
gip = divider.pow(1/cInterger);
```

However when I call `System.out.println(gip);` it shows the result with no decimal places.
How do I define the number of decimal places I want?

Comment: Have you looked in setting the precision like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482889/set-specific-precision-of-a-bigdecimal

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin gip is also a BigDecimal. Updated post.

Comment: You're making it hard for people to answer by excluding your type definitions for the variables involved.  From the code above, I have to investigate return types before I can determine what gip is. Also, this code is odd.  Why are you converting an integer to a string for the BigDecimal constructor, when the constructor supports integers?  At any rate, assuming gip is a BigDecimal, you want to use gip.toPlainString().

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(gip.toPlainString());
```

Comment: And to clarify, when you call System.out.println(gip), println will automatically perform gip.toString().  In this case, the toString isn't producing the output you want to see.