# Convert string to BigDecimal in java

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I am reading a currency from `XML` into Java.

```
String currency = "135.69";
```

When I convert this to `BigDecimal` I get:

```
 System.out.println(new BigDecimal(135.69));
```

Output:

```
135.68999999999999772626324556767940521240234375.
```

Why is it that it outputs this many numbers? How can I avoid this? All I want is for it to output 135.69.

Comment: You sure type of `currency` is string? And you're reading the value as string only?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set specific precision of a BigDecimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482889/set-specific-precision-of-a-bigdecimal)

Comment: Your currency is not even a `String` to start with; just use the `BigDecimal` constructor having a `String` as an argument.

Comment: There might be many solutions, but do you know why it happens? Read this if you don't: http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-are-floating-point-calculations-so-inaccurate.htm

Answer (score 181):

The BigDecimal(double) constructor can have unpredictable behaviors. It is preferable to use BigDecimal(String) or BigDecimal.valueOf(double).

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(135.69)); //135.68999999999999772626324556767940521240234375
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("135.69")); // 135.69
System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(135.69)); // 135.69
```

The documentation for [BigDecimal(double)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(double)) explains in detail:

> 1. The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable. One might assume that writing new BigDecimal(0.1) in Java creates a
>    BigDecimal which is exactly equal to 0.1 (an unscaled value of 1, with
>    a scale of 1), but it is actually equal to
>    0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625. This is because 0.1 cannot be represented exactly as a double (or, for that
>    matter, as a binary fraction of any finite length). Thus, the value
>    that is being passed in to the constructor is not exactly equal to
>    0.1, appearances notwithstanding.
> 2. The String constructor, on the other hand, is perfectly predictable: writing new BigDecimal("0.1") creates a BigDecimal which
>    is exactly equal to 0.1, as one would expect. Therefore, it is
>    generally recommended that the String constructor be used in
>    preference to this one.
> 3. When a double must be used as a source for a BigDecimal, note that this constructor provides an exact conversion; it does not give
>    the same result as converting the double to a String using the
>    Double.toString(double) method and then using the BigDecimal(String)
>    constructor. To get that result, use the static valueOf(double)
>    method.

Comment: What would you say if you are in a service and were only being passed in a string. Note it could be an Integer, Double etc.

Comment: In that case I would use new BigDecimal ("string_value"). In this way, it would function correctly for both integer and decimal.

Answer (score 40):

```
String currency = "135.69";
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(currency));

//will print 135.69
```

Comment: Not good practice to use constructor to instantiate "String", "BigInteger", "BigDecimal" and primitive-wrapper classes . https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2129

Comment: @NateGetch (I know it is old) but have you read the link you provided? It itself is listing `new BigDecimal("42.0")` as compliant solution! The alternatives it states should be used, are autoboxing (does not work with BigDecimal) and `valueOf()`  (no such method that takes a `String`)

Answer (score 4):

You are storing 135.69 as String in currency. But instead of passing variable currency, you are again passing 135.69(double value) into new BigDecimal().
So you are seeing a lot of numbers in the output.
If you pass the currency variable, your output will be 135.69

Answer (score 3):

May I add something. If you are using currency you should use Scale(2), and you should probably figure out a round method.

Answer (score 3):

***BigDecimal b = BigDecimal.valueOf(d);***

```
import java.math.*; 

public class Test { 

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 

        // Creating a Double Object 
        Double d = new Double("785.254"); 

        /// Assigning the bigdecimal value of ln to b 
        BigDecimal b = BigDecimal.valueOf(d); 

        // Displaying BigDecimal value 
        System.out.println("The Converted BigDecimal value is: " + b); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Spring Framework provides an excellent utils class for achieving this.

Util class : [NumberUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/NumberUtils.html)

String to BigDecimal conversion -

```
NumberUtils.parseNumber("135.00", BigDecimal.class);
```

Answer (score -9):

Hi Guys you cant convert directly string to bigdecimal

you need to first convert it into long after that u will  convert big decimal

```
String currency = "135.69"; 
Long rate1=Long.valueOf((currency ));            
System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(rate1));
```

Comment: (1) "*you cant convert directly string to bigdecimal*" - you sure can: `new BigDecimal("135.69")`; (2) "*convert it into long*" - that is **not** possible for a decimal number like `135.69`