# GCP Dataflow droppedDueToClosedWindow & Commit request for stage S8 and key 8 is larger than 2GB

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, dataflow

We run into problems with our Dataflow on Google Cloud. Our pipeline consists of various input steps, which get data pushed in with GCP PubSub. We then aggregate the data and sort it. These [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5uy2.png) steps are clearly too heavy for Dataflow and the window we configured. We get an exception [2] on the step. Also we see these metrics:

```
droppedDueToClosedWindow    3,838,662   Bids/AggregateExchangeOrders
droppedDueToClosedWindow    21,060,627  Asks/AggregateExchangeOrders
```

Now I am seeking advice how to attack this issue. Should I break down the steps, so for example iterations and sorting can be done with parallel steps?

Is there a way to get more information about what exactly happens? 
Should we increase the number of workers? (Currently 1).

We are rather new with Dataflow. .. Good advice is most welcome.

Edit: I am adding a bit of details on the steps.

This is how the steps below are 'chained' together:

```
    @Override
    public PCollection<KV<KV<String, String>, List<ExchangeOrder>>> expand(PCollection<KV<String, KV<String, String>>> input) {
        return input.apply("PairWithType", new ByPairWithType(type))
                .apply("UnfoldExchangeOrders", new ByAggregatedExchangeOrders())
                .apply("AggregateExchangeOrders", GroupByKey.<KV<String, String>, KV<String, KV<BigDecimal, BigDecimal>>>create())
                .apply("ReorderExchangeOrders", ParDo.of(new ReorderExchangeOrders()));
    }
```

AggregateExchangeOrders:

So here, clearly we iterate through a collection of orders, and parse the type (twice), so it'a big decimal. 
Which makes me think, we could skip one parse step as described here: 
[Convert string to BigDecimal in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28783918/convert-string-to-bigdecimal-in-java)

```
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
            KV<String, KV<String, String>> key = c.element().getKey();
            List<KV<String, String>> value = c.element().getValue();

            value.forEach(
                    exchangeOrder -> {
                        try {
                            BigDecimal unitPrice = BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.valueOf(exchangeOrder.getKey()));
                            BigDecimal quantity = BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.valueOf(exchangeOrder.getValue()));
                            if (quantity.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) != 0) {
                                // Exclude exchange orders with no quantity.
                                    c.output(KV.of(key.getValue(), KV.of(key.getKey(), KV.of(unitPrice, quantity))));
                            }
                        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                            // Exclude exchange orders with invalid element.
                        }
                    });
        }
```

...next we group and sort. (And optionally reverse it), it seems this step is not taking a huge load.

ReorderExchangeOrders:

```
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
        KV<String, String> pairAndType = c.element().getKey();
        Iterable<KV<String, KV<BigDecimal, BigDecimal>>> exchangeOrderBook = c.element().getValue();
        List<ExchangeOrder> list = new ArrayList<>();

        exchangeOrderBook.forEach(exchangeOrder -> list.add(
                new ExchangeOrder(exchangeOrder.getKey(), exchangeOrder.getValue().getKey(), exchangeOrder.getValue().getValue())));

        // Asks are sorted in ASC order
        Collections.sort(list);

        // Bids are sorted in DSC order
        if (pairAndType.getValue().equals(EXCHANGE_ORDER_TYPE.BIDS.toString())) {
            Collections.reverse(list);
        }

        c.output(KV.of(pairAndType, list));
    }
```

[ 1 ] Dataflow screenshot:

[image: Dataflow Screenshot]

[ 2 ] Exception: Commit request for stage S8 and key 8 is larger than 2GB and cannot be processed.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Commit request for stage S8 and key 8 is larger than 2GB and cannot be processed. This may be caused by grouping a very large amount of data in a single window without using Combine, or by producing a large amount of data from a single input element.
    com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$Commit.getSize(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:327)
    com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.lambda$new$0(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:342)
```

Comment: Can you be more clear regarding the sort of aggregation that you're doing? Are you getting all elements together in a list and then sorting them? How many elements do you usually expect within a window?

Comment: On the number of elements, so it will be about 100 per input stream. (We have 3 running now and expect many more). The input is also a fixed time (every 10 sec.) so, I actually doubt our pipeline should be unbounded.

Comment: Can you add more detail about the sort of aggregation? Are your elements very large? A 'commit request' is trying to send data between to stages (e.g. if there's a group-by-key, or some other non-ParDoy operation)

Comment: Ah, Yes the info still missing is how these steps are used. I will do another edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is kind of straightforward.
The root cause of the problem, as many of the comments point out, is that the structure that contains all the results for one of the DoFn's is larger than 2GB, and your best option would be to partition your data in some way to make your work units smaller.

In the code I see that some of the structures returned by DoFn's are nested structures in the form KV>. This arrangement forces Dataflow to send the whole response back in one monolithic bundle, and prevents it from chunking it into smaller pieces.

One possible solution would be to use composite keys instead of nested structures for as long as possible in the pipeline, and only combine them when strictly necessary.

For example,

> instead of KV>, the DoFn could return
>
> KV<(concat(Key1, Key2)), Value>

This would split the work units into much smaller sets that can then be dispatched in parallel to multiple workers.

To answer the other questions, increasing the number of workers will have no effect as the huge collection generated by DoFn looks like is not splittable. Adding logging to see how the collection arrives at 2GB might provide useful tips to prevent this.

Comment: Thanks @MonicaPC, I now use custom types, and concatenated keys as you suggest. Also tuning the windowing helped a lot.