# Calculate an expression in java which is accurate upto 19 digits

Tags: java, formula, calculator, bigdecimal

I have an expression in string for example
formula="333333333333333333+222222222222222222"
I am trying to calculate the value of the expression to be accurate upto 18 digits.
to calculate I am using scriptEngine in java as the expression could be any expression however I am getting the result as 55555555555555552
Here is my code

```
ScriptEngineManager scriptEngineManager= new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine scriptEngine=scriptEngineManager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
Object result=scriptEngine.eval(formula);
```

In object I get exponential to which I remove by converting to bigDecimal string. However the calculation is not accurate if I use scriptEngineManager.
I also tried converting the numbers to big decimal by replacing all the numbers with 'new java.math.BigDecimal(number)' but still I get inaccurate value.
Do I manually have to create a parser in which I add bigdecimals using their functions bigdecimal.add(bigdecimal) , however in that case I have to take care of BODMAS rule as well as it's an expression that I have to take care of.

Please help me how to calculate a string expression which is accurate upto 18 digits.
Thanks in advance

Comment: For complete accuracy, you'll need `BigDecimal` with `String` creation of the numbers

Comment: Hi @g00se , can you elaborate and explain more?

Comment: If the values in your expression only contain digits, and no decimal points or exponentiation, you probably should use [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Comment: `new BigDecimal("333333333333333333").add(new BigDecimal("222222222222222222"));` I mentioned that class as I assumed that you won't always be using integral values. If I'm wrong, use `BigInteger`

Comment: @g00se I can use the add() function however I have an expression, That expression can can contain any number of operands and any arithmetic operator +,-,*,/ . So I cannot manually use BigDecimals function

Comment: Well you'd probably need to find a scripting engine that can be instructed to use arbitrary precision

Comment: I haven't looked into this script engine, but as you set it to JS mode, precision is probably that of a JS number.

Comment: Bear in mind that API support for scripting finished at 1.8 so you'll need to find something independent

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string to BigDecimal in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28783918/convert-string-to-bigdecimal-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to solve this by using an external library known as EvalEx.
Maven link- [evalExMvn](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.udojava/EvalEx/2.1).
I was able to set the precision upto 18 digits and was able to evaluate the string expression.

```
import com.udojava.EvalEx.Expression;  
import com.udojava.EvalEx.Expression.ExpressionException;

 Expression expr = new Expression(formula);
 expr.setPrecision(18); // Set precision to 18 digits
 BigDecimal number= expr.eval();
```