# Calculating precision of sum of fractions

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I have this mathematical expression :

∑(2k+1)/(2k)! , k =0,... ,∞ , it is sum from zero to infinity of all fractions in the form (2k+1)/(2k)!

I want to create a method which when passed an integer "n", it will output me the result with n digits after the decimal point.This expression first 100 digits can be viewed here : https://miniwebtool.com/first-n-digits-of-e/?number=100

Here is my code, what I have attempted

```
package pi.strategy;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.LongStream;

public class Tester {

    public static BigInteger factorial(long k) {
        return LongStream.range(2, k + 1).mapToObj(BigInteger::valueOf).reduce(BigInteger.ONE,
                (current, factSoFar) -> factSoFar.multiply(current));
    }

    protected static BigDecimal strategy(int precision) {


        return IntStream.range(0, precision).mapToObj(i -> computeMember(i, precision + 2))
               .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, (current, sumSoFar) -> sumSoFar.add(current));
    }


    static BigDecimal computeMember(int n, int scale) {


        final BigDecimal dominator = new BigDecimal((2 * n) + 1);
        final BigDecimal enumenator = new BigDecimal(factorial(2 * n));
        // System.out.println("Temp Result:" + dominator.divide(enumenator, scale,
        // RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
        BigDecimal res = dominator.divide(enumenator, scale, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

        return res;



    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(strategy(6));

    }

}
```

The problem is that when I add fractions, sometimes they will overflow and create extra digits at the end.
In case of strategy(6) , it outputs extra digits 2.71828179 instead of 2.718281

In the case of strategy(5) it outputs wrong answer 2.7182787 instead of 2.71828. Any ideas where is he problem and how can I limit it correctly to output with precision?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set specific precision of a BigDecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482889/set-specific-precision-of-a-bigdecimal)

Comment: Nah not really , I am trying at runtime to stop adding.Imagine if it takes 1 hour to calculate the whole number and you just want the first 5 digits or 10.That is my goal , to stop the computation when we have reached our precision.

Comment: If _at runtime to stop adding_ is your goal, you should invest into math. To compute how many terms you need for a given precision, look at the Taylor theorem, specifically at the [estimates for the remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Estimates_for_the_remainder).

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that the result is being rounded after each step, and so rounding errors are being summed.

You should use a Fraction class (such as the one described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/474612) and extract the decimal representation at the end of the process.

EDIT

I'm not a Java developer, so I don't have a proper dev environment set up on my machine. I've tried to update your code to use the BigFraction class I linked earlier:

```
package pi.strategy;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.LongStream;

public class Tester {
    public static BigInteger factorial(long k) {
        return LongStream.range(2, k + 1).mapToObj(BigInteger::valueOf).reduce(BigInteger.ONE,
                (current, factSoFar) -> factSoFar.multiply(current));
    }

    protected static BigFraction strategy(int precision) {
        return IntStream.range(0, precision).mapToObj(i -> computeMember(i, precision + 2))
               .reduce(BigFraction.ZERO, (current, sumSoFar) -> sumSoFar.add(current));
    }


    static BigFraction computeMember(int n, int scale) {
        final BigDecimal numerator = new BigDecimal((2 * n) + 1);
        final BigDecimal denominator = new BigDecimal(factorial(2 * n));

        return new BigFraction(numerator, denominator);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        final BigFraction result = strategy(6);
        System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println(result.toBigDecimal());
    }
}
```

It may be more efficient to refactor this code so that it doesn't use the factorial function or factorials are cached and don't have to be recomputed each time from 1.